# IISExpress - setting environment variable for PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables, iis-express

I have a batch file which sets an environment variable, then runs IISExpress which I use for my php application. Example:

```
set MY_ENV = "devmode"
iisexpress.exe /config:myapp.config /site:myapp  /trace:e
```

In index.php, if I output the results of `phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT)`, I can see the environment variable set correctly:

[image: MY_ENV is set correctly]

However, `getenv('MY_ENV')` comes back with null.

How should I set the Windows environment variable so getenv() picks it up?